# Is there any way to get user subscription or watch history through youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to get user watch history or channel subscriptions from youtube API using oauth? I've checked around but can't find anything.
It looks like the most that can be done is get a users channel data which doesn't have much information.

Comment: Concerning subscriptions: [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) endpoint does not help you?

Comment: Yes that does, but we really need the watch history. Any ideas? Thanks for responding.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to retrieve it consists in web-scraping [this webpage](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history).